# How to send the value of two dependent dropdowns via an AJAX post request to a Django view?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I'm currently trying to send the values of two dropdowns to a django view. My code would have worked properly had the dropdowns been independent. The problem is that it isn't the case. The first one updates the second one, so I need to make my AJAX post request once the second dropdown has been updated.

Here is my current html/Javascript code:

```
<select name="d1" class="toChange">
    {% for item in items1 %}
    <option val="{{ item }}"> {{ item }} </option>    
    {% endfor %}
</select>

<select name="d2">
    {% for item in items2 %}
    <option val="{{ item }}"> {{ item }} </option>    
    {% endfor %}
  </select>


<script type="text/javascript">
  function dropdownChange () {
    var value_d1 = $(".toChange option:selected").val();
    var value_d2 = $("select[name=d2] option:selected").val();
    $.ajax({
            url: '/myApp/templates/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'d1': value_d1, 'd2': value_d2},
            success: function(data) {
              var str = '';
              data.forEach(function(opt){
              str += '<option value="' + opt + '">' + opt + '</option>';
              });
              document.getElementById("d2").innerHTML = str;
            }
    });
    $(".toChange").change(dropdownChange);
```

So here the change in d1 updates d2 but the AJAX call is made before d2 gets updated and therefore sends the wrong value to my view. How can I overcome this issue?

UPDATE: adding the code suggested by TM.96

```
 <select id="d1" name="d1" class="toChange">
    {% for item in items1 %}
    <option val="{{ item }}"> {{ item }} </option>    
    {% endfor %}
  </select>

  <select id="d2" name="d2">
    {% for item in items2 %}
    <option val="{{ item }}"> {{ item }} </option>    
    {% endfor %}
  </select>


<script type="text/javascript">

let select1 = document.getElementById('d1');
let select2 = document.getElementById('d2');

function onChangeSelect1() {

    window.select2.value = window.select1.options[window.select1.selectedIndex].value;

    onChangeSelect2();
}

function onChangeSelect2() {
    console.log('Value of Select 1: ' + window.select1.value);
    console.log('Value of Select 2: ' + window.select2.value);

    $.ajax({
            url: '/myApp/templates/',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'d1': select1, 'd2': select2},
            success: function(data) {
              var str = '';
              data.forEach(function(opt){
              str += '<option value="' + opt + '">' + opt + '</option>';
              });
              document.getElementById("d2").innerHTML = str;
            }
    }); 
}
$(".toChange").change(dropdownChange);

</script>
```

UPDATE 2:

```
def MyView(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax:


        result_r = request.POST.get('d1')
        result_d = request.POST.get('d2')
        query_results = data_immo.objects.all()
        regions = data_immo.objects.values_list("nom_reg", flat=True).distinct().order_by('nom_reg')
        departments = data_immo.objects.values_list("insee_dep").filter(Q(nom_reg=result_r)).distinct()
        cities = data_immo.objects.values_list("nom_com").filter(Q(insee_dep=result_d)).distinct()

        print(departments)

        query_results_dict = {
        'query_results': query_results,
        'regions': regions,
        'departments': departments,
        'reg': result_r
        }

        departmentsVar=[]
        for item in departments:
            item = int(item[0])
            departmentsVar.append(item)

        departmentsVar.sort()
        departmentsVar = json.dumps(departmentsVar)

        citiesVar=[]
        for item in cities:
            citiesVar.append(item)

        citiesVar.sort()
        citiesVar = json.dumps(citiesVar)


        return HttpResponse(departmentsVar, content_type='application/json')
```

Technically, I need to return both departmentsVar and citiesVar but for some reasons my attempts have failed. It seems that I can only return one variable (so here departmentsVar). I tried to add the two in a dictionary but it didn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly, but I guess there are multiple ways to do this. You could for example just add an `onchange` attribute with a javascript function as value to your second dropdown. So if you select something in dropdown 1 then dropdown 2 gets updated and fires the `onchange` event that in turn calls the javascript function with the ajax requests. If that's not what you meant, maybe you can specify it a bit more for me?

Comment: @TM.96: yes that is the kind of solution I'm looking for indeed. Unfortunately I tried something similar but it didn't trigger the second dropdown. I'm very new to Javascript though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I put up a minimal working example for you below:

**Server side:**

*urls.py*

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('Ajax/Test', views.ajax_test),
]
```

*views.py*

```
def ajax_test(request):
    return JsonResponse(request.GET)
```

**Client side:**

*HTML*

```
<label for="selectCity">City:</label>
<select id="selectCity" onchange="onChangeSelectCity()">
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option --</option>
    <option value="1">Munich</option>
    <option value="2">Los Angeles</option>
</select>

<label for="selectState">State:</label>
<select id="selectState" onchange="onChangeSelectState()">
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option --</option>
    <option value="1">Bavaria</option>
    <option value="2">California</option>
</select>

<label for="selectCountry">Country:</label>
<select id="selectCountry" onchange="onChangeSelectCountry()">
    <option disabled selected value> -- select an option --</option>
   <option value="1">Germany</option>
   <option value="2">United States</option>
</select>
```

*Javascript*

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- JavaScript example code -->
<script>
// Set global variables. You can also set these inside the functions and use 
// them as local variables.
// When you declare a variable outside the function, it is added in the 
// window object internally.
let selectCity = document.getElementById('selectCity');
let selectState = document.getElementById('selectState');
let selectCountry = document.getElementById('selectCountry');

// Triggers if Select City changes.
function onChangeSelectCity() {
    // Print values of the select fields in console.
    console.log('On change Select City:');
    console.log('Value of Select City: ' + window.selectCity.value);
    console.log('Value of Select State: ' + window.selectState.value);
    console.log('Value of Select Country: ' + window.selectCountry.value);

    // Call function that is also called if Select State changes.
    onChangeSelectState(window.selectCity.value);
}

// Triggers if Select State changes.
function onChangeSelectState(value = 0) {
    // If function got called from onChangeSelectCity.
    if (value > 0) {
        window.selectState.value = value;
    }

    // Print values of the select fields in console.
    console.log('On change Select State:');
    console.log('Value of Select City: ' + window.selectCity.value);
    console.log('Value of Select State: ' + window.selectState.value);
    console.log('Value of Select Country: ' + window.selectCountry.value);

    // Call function that is also called if Select Country changes.
    onChangeSelectCountry(window.selectState.value);
}

// Triggers if Select Country changes.
function onChangeSelectCountry(value = 0) {
    // If function got called from onChangeSelectState.
    if (value > 0) {
        window.selectCountry.value = value;
    }

    // Print values of the select fields in console.
    console.log('On change Select Country:');
    console.log('Value of Select City: ' + window.selectCity.value);
    console.log('Value of Select State: ' + window.selectState.value);
    console.log('Value of Select Country: ' + window.selectCountry.value);

    // Put your ajax code here...
    let url = 'Ajax/Test';

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            'city': window.selectCity.value,
            'state': window.selectState.value,
            'country': window.selectCountry.value
        },
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

**Explanation:**

I put up three select fields (City, State and Country).

1. If City gets changed, State and Country will get updated corresponding to City.
2. If State gets changed, Country will get updated corresponding to State. City won't get changed.
3. If Country gets changed, nothing gets updated. City and State won't get changed.

The ajax call gets triggered on all three cases and sends the correct values (either none or set) to the django view. Also the django view returns the values back and they will get correctly printed in the console.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Just to confirm, the part where you tell me to put the ajax code, you mean the line starting at "$.ajax({" or shall I start at "function dropdownChange () {" ? Because I've tried both, but it didn't get the expected result.

Comment: Just the ajax procedure starting with `$.ajax({...})`. What exactly isn't working as expected? Did you check the console output and was that correct? Did you get the correct values (or at least the same as in the console) in your django view function?

Comment: I can't even trigger the ajax bit anymore and no idea where it comes from. But I think I will find a workaround and do something else. Just a question though. Do I need to update the selects and add "onChange" to use your functions? Something like this for instance:<select id="select1" name="select1" onChange="onChangeSelect1()">
Or is that unnecessary?

Comment: Well, just to be sure, you are putting the javascript inside the HTML file After the select fields? No, you don‘t need to have the onchange Attribute on the html select field, but you Need to catch the change Event of Your select fields if you want to do something After the value of the select Field changes. Well if you Could Update your question above with some More Details what exactly isn‘t working or a running minimal example, I can Maybe help you More.

Comment: Thank you, I just updated the code, hopefully it can help.

Comment: The first thing i can say is, that you‘re not catching any change event, so none of the functions will get called right now. Second could you add the code of the corresponding django view function as well. And third could you tell me what you want to do with the values of the two select fields in the view AND what you want to do on the page after the ajax call was successfull.

Comment: 1/ Ok, so shouldn't I use the onChange attribute to capture the change event? If not, what do you suggest? 2/ I've added the view, hopefully it will help. 3/ The final idea of this is the following: when the user selects a value in the first dropdown, the change needs to trigger a change in the second dropdown which is dependent from the first one. Finally, the same should happen so a third dropdown gets updated. I need 3 cascading dropdowns (like continents->countries->cities). I've seen few examples on the net but it felt too complex for my level, so I decided to use the method above.

Comment: I updated my answer with a fully correct working example. You CAN use the onChange attribute on the HTML select field, but you could for example also catch the onChange event purely with javascript with an event handler. Thats up to you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and efforts, much appreciated! I'm wondering though, you said in your explanation that "If Country gets changed, nothing gets updated. City and State won't get changed". That's not really convenient. Would it be too complex to get everything updated as expected? Because it's not user friendly to have a city not matching to its country (just to be clear, I'm not asking you to do it, you've done already a lot, just curious).

Comment: I just made up some example logic, if you choose Munich then Bavaria and Germany gets selected, if you choose Bavaria then it‘s Not obvious (With more german cities as options of course) That you want munich for example and Not Stuttgart. But yeah it‘s totally up to you how you want to update the select fields, i just wanted to implement a simple minimal update logic just for explanation!